# Trying to change the body in presave nodeapi - not working

Tags: 6, nodes

I'm trying to make a small modification in the body a node when it's saved:

```
function radicalislam_utils_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
      if ($op == 'presave') 
             $node->body = 'test';
}
```

but what I'm getting is strange. when I view the node, i really see only "test" as the body. but when i go edit the post, i see all that previously on the body and "test" appended in the end...

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the body of a node differs from its teaser, it will show both when editing
(it'll append the real body to the teaser, which is why it looks like you're still seeing the old version of the body).

In other words: make sure your body *and* your teaser are both altered before saving.